# Replicate a case when statement in Jinja

Tags: sql, jinja2, dbt

I want to replicate a simple case-when statement with a jinja block in dbt.
How can I achieve this?

Here is my statement:

```
CASE status
    WHEN 0 THEN 'pending'
    WHEN 1 THEN 'ordered'
    WHEN 2 THEN 'shipped'
    WHEN 3 THEN 'received'
    WHEN 4 THEN 'delivered'
    ELSE NULL
END as status_mapping
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple options. First, you can define the mappings in an array or dict (if the ids are not a sequence) and loop through it to produce the full case statement:

```
{% set statuses = ['pending', 'ordered', 'shipped', 'received', 'delivered'] %}
CASE STATUS
{% for status in statuses %}
WHEN {{ loop.index - 1 }} THEN '{{ status }}'
{% endfor %}
ELSE NULL END STATUS_MAPPING
```

The other option is to put the mappings into a CSV, load it as a seed data file in DBT (https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/build/seeds), then join with the seed data as a `ref`.

Create a file called `status_mappings.csv`:

```
status_code,status
0,pending
1,ordered
2,shipped
3,received
4,delivered
```

Run `dbt seed`, then add

```
WITH STATUS_MAPPINGS AS (
  SELECT * FROM {{ ref('status_mappings') }}
}

SELECT S.STATUS
FROM MY_TABLE T1
JOIN STATUS_MAPPINGS SM ON T1.STATUS_CODE = SM.STATUS_CODE
```

Comment: Actually status list is not a sequence in my dataset, i.e. after 4, there is 6 and then goes on consecutively. Is there a way to tweak the jinja loop?

Comment: @kimi - Then you can replace `statuses` with a `dict` and iterate through the key/value pairs. Personally, I would recommend going the seed file route. It's a little cleaner IMO.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a macro to insert reusable SQL snippets across different queries, which is one possible reason you might want to do this.

You could define the macro as follows:

```sql
-- yourproject/macros/status_mapping.sql
{% macro status_mapping(status) %}
CASE {{ status }}
    WHEN 0 THEN 'pending'
    WHEN 1 THEN 'ordered'
    WHEN 2 THEN 'shipped'
    WHEN 3 THEN 'received'
    WHEN 4 THEN 'delivered'
    ELSE NULL
 END
{% endmacro %}
```

(I have kept the definition flexible)

... and call it in a model e.g. as follows:

```sql
-- yourproject/models/base/base__orders.sql
    SELECT
        order_id,
        status_code,
        {{ status_mapping('status_code') }} AS status
      FROM
        {{ source('your_dataset', 'orders') }}
```

Note the use of quotes around the field name, same as with the built-in `source` macro two lines below. By including the field name as a macro argument instead of hard-coding it (and keeping the aliasing `AS status` outside the macro) you allow yourself flexibility to change things in future.

This would then be compiled when you run DBT to something like:

```sql
    SELECT
        order_id,
        status_code,
CASE status_code
    WHEN 0 THEN 'pending'
    WHEN 1 THEN 'ordered'
    WHEN 2 THEN 'shipped'
    WHEN 3 THEN 'received'
    WHEN 4 THEN 'delivered'
    ELSE NULL
 END AS status
      FROM
        your_dataset.orders
```